# Piping a pipe-delimited flat file into python for use in Pandas and Stats

Tags: python, pipe, flat

I have searched a lot, but haven't found an answer to this.

I am trying to pipe in a flat file with data and put into something python read and that I can do analysis with (for instance, perform a t-test).

First, I created a simple pipe delimited flat file:

> ```
> 1|2
> 3|4
> 4|5
> 1|6
> 2|7
> 3|8
> 8|9
> ```

and saved it as "simpledata".

Then I created a bash script in nano as

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from scipy import stats 

A = sys.stdin.read()
print A
paired_sample = stats.ttest_rel(A[:,0],A[:,1])
print "The t-statistic is %.3f and the p-value is %.3f." % paired_sample
```

Then I save the script as pairedttest.sh and run it as

```
 cat simpledata | pairedttest.sh
```

The error I get is

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Your error is from `A[:,0]` and `A[:,1]`. Drop the commas and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Hi Adam thanks for that. Using A[:0] and A[:1] gives me another error    `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: You'll have to let us know what the other error is, we can't read your mind or your computer screen :)

Comment: Sorry-- I pressed enter thinking it would be a new line. No biggie-- I think I have it solved or nearly there with @Dano's help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to call this?:

```
paired_sample = stats.ttest_rel([1,3,4,1,2,3,8], [2,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

If so, you can't do it the way you're trying. `A` is just a string when you read it from stdin, so you can't index it the way you're trying. You need to build the two lists from the string. The most obvious way is like this:

```
left = []
right = []
for line in A.splitlines():
    l, r = line.split("|")
    left.append(int(l))
    right.append(int(r))
print left
print right
```

This will output:

```
[1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 8]
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So you can call `stats.ttest_rel(left, right)`

Or to be really clever and make a (nearly impossible to read) one-liner out of it:

```
z = zip(*[map(int, line.split("|")) for line in A.splitlines()])
```

This will output:

```
[(1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 8), (2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]
```

So you can call `stats.ttest_rel(*z)`

Comment: Thanks I knew there was a way to use `zip` and glob unpacking to do this. I'm going to delete my answer -- yours is much better.

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks for the `splitlines()` tip!

Comment: @dano I think I am almost there-- but now I am getting the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "###/pairedttest.sh", line 23, in <module>
    paired_sample = stats.ttest_rel(left, right)
  File "#/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 3379, in ttest_rel
    d = (a - b).astype(np.float64)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: It's worth nothing that in my tests with a large `A`, the simpler approach is faster. It's not surprising since we're iterating over the values several times "clever" version.

Comment: I should note that everything is fine doing `stats.ttest_rel([1,3,4,1,2,3,8], [2,4,5,6,7,8,9])`, but when I do `stats.ttest_rel(left, right)` I get the error. Do you think this may be because left and right have single quotes around the numbers? THanks!

Comment: @dano -- it appears that I am (not purposefully). Basically I am now following what you did in making the objects left and right, but when I use them in the ttest_rel command, I get the error